Addressing Heteroscedasticity in Mixed Effects Models with glmmTMB and DHARMa in R
I am analyzing ecological data in R, where I aim to understand the impact of urbanization on species trends. My response variable is the coefficient of species trends (estimate), and my main predictor is the coefficient of urbanization trends (urb_trend).
I've shared the dataset (final_df.csv) and the R script (Hypotheses.R) that contains the code and detailed information about the data and the analysis approach on GitHub. You can access them here: https://github.com/Paucom9/URBAN_TRENDS. The data is public, and I welcome any advice or insights. However, please do not publish, share, or use this data without permission.

I'm using the glmmTMB package to fit a mixed effects model, accounting for random effects by SPECIES and nested within Country.Name / SITE_ID. My model looks like this:
library(glmmTMB)
mod_h1 <- glmmTMB(estimate ~ urb_trend + (1|SPECIES) + (1|Country.Name/SITE_ID),
                  data = final_df,
                  weights = inverse_variance_weights,
                  family = gaussian)

I've encountered issues with heteroscedasticity, as evident from diagnostic plots generated by the DHARMa package.
sim_res <- simulateResiduals(fittedModel = mod_h1)
plot(sim_res)


Despite trying several approaches to mitigate this—like transforming the response variable, adding various predictors to the model (including polynomial terms), adjusting weights, and experimenting with the dispformula—the issue persists.

What strategies within glmmTMB or other packages might better address heteroscedasticity in the context of ecological data analysis?


How can I more effectively determine which variables might be influencing the variability of errors in my model?


Have I overlooked an alternative approach, transformation, or model specification that could help resolve this issue?


Any advice, especially from those familiar with ecological data analysis using glmmTMB and DHARMa, would be greatly appreciated.

